# Huber loss function parameter in GBM R package

Tags: r, gbm

I'm using GBM package for a regression problem. I would like to test the Huber loss function. I can use the "huberized" value for the distribution. However, how do you set the cutting edge parameter?

Maybe I missed it somewhere in the help.

Comment: I assume you are trying to tamper with the sensitivity of outlier cutoff? I have a gut feeling that you need `alpha` as (if my memory serves me right) it is used to adjust outlier sensitivity. I am really sorry I can't offer more help.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about the parameter that makes the threshold between Gaussian and Laplace loss functions. I will try alpha although I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: In fact I thought the "huberized" was the right distribution, but it is only for 0-1 output. Any idea on which one corresponds to Huber loss function for regression?

Comment: There was a passage regarding `alpha` in the GBM manual, but it limits to the notion that `distribution` must be described as a `list`. The passage can be found in page 7. Unfortunately I can't recall how one corresponds to HBF for regression.